# Increase only build number of a react-native application using react-native-version

Tags: react-native, npm-version

I'm trying to incease only the version number by running `npm version -b` but it doesn't seem to work without using a specific version number / patch / minor/ major.

Is there a way to achieve this use case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats the '-b' flag supposed to do? how do you want to increment the version? provide an example please: before: x.y.z, after: ?.?.?

Comment: According to the documentation '-b' should only increment build number (https://github.com/stovmascript/react-native-version).

My current version is 1.0.1 (build no. 35), and I want it to be 1.0.1 (build no. 36).